# how to get the value of the hovered time on input range

Tags: javascript, jquery

my question may have been a bit vague so ill explain it in detail here. im trying to develop a simple video player on a page. im using input range to display the file duration and current time like any standard player. here is my script.

```
<script>
        var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimeText, durtimeText, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn;
        function initializePlayer() {

            //creating global object
            vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
            playbtn = document.getElementById('playpausebtn');
            seekslider = document.getElementById('seekslider');
            curtimeText = document.getElementById('curtimeText');
            durtimeText = document.getElementById('durtimeText');
            mutebtn = document.getElementById('mutebtn');
            volumeslider = document.getElementById('volumeslider');
            fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById('fullscreenbtn');

            //creating event for objects
            playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
            seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
            vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
            mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
            volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);
            fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen, false);
        }

        window.onload = initializePlayer;

        function playPause() {
            if (vid.paused) {
                vid.play();
                playbtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
            } else {
                vid.pause();
                playbtn.innerHTML = "Play";
            }

        }
        function vidSeek() {
            var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
            vid.currentTime = seekto;
        }
        function seektimeupdate() {
            var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
            seekslider.value = nt;
            var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
            var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
            var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
            var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);
            if (cursecs < 10) {
                cursecs = "0" + cursecs;
            }
            if (dursecs < 10) {
                dursecs = "0" + dursecs;
            }
            if (curmins < 10) {
                curmins = "0" + curmins;
            }
            if (durmins < 10) {
                durmins = "0" + durmins;
            }
            curtimeText.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
            durtimeText.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
        }
        function vidmute() {

            if (vid.muted) {
                vid.muted = false;
                mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
            } else {
                vid.muted = true;
                mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
            }
        }
        function setvolume() {
            vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
        }
        function toggleFullScreen() {
            if (vid.requestFullScreen) {
                vid.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }
</script>
```

and my HTML code:

```
<div id="Video_player_box">
    <video id="my_video">
        <source src="Videos/cowhand.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!-- Your browser does not support HTML5 video.-->
    </video>
    <div id="Video_controls_bar">
        <button id="playpausebtn">Play</button>             
        <span id="curtimeText"></span>
        <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.1"> 
        <span id="durtimeText"></span>
        <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
        <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
        <button id="fullscreenbtn">[&nbsp;&nbsp;]</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

now what i want to do is to display the time of wherever the user is pointing at seekslider on a small tooltip. like if the video is 10min long, and the user is point at the middle of the rangebar (seekslider) i want a small tooltip to shows that the user is pointing at i.e 5:01  but i really have no idea on how to code that! i would appreciate any kind of help on how to implement this function.

Comment: There should be a straight forward way to accomplish this... but otherwise you could use a mousemove event: take the clientX and figure out where your mouse is relative to the slider. From there you could create a percentage that can be used to calculate 'current' seek position.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple function that should get you on your way. It uses the event data to get all the necessary numbers and returns a value based on the slider's `max` attribute.

```js
function calcSliderPos(e) {
  return ( e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft ) / e.target.clientWidth * parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute('max'));
}

//attach to slider and fire on mousemove
document.getElementById('seekslider').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  //inject the value into the durtime span
  document.getElementById('durtimeText').innerHTML = calcSliderPos(e).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.1"> 
<span id="durtimeText"></span>
```

Note that this only gives you an estimated position. I believe the only way to really get an 100% accurate position is to select a spot on the slider and fetch that value.

Answer (score 4):

Drawing on [Jesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473890/3869670) as well as [this page](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip) and some of my own experimentation, I took it a step further and figured out the code to get the tooltip to follow the mouse.

[I created a Codepen](http://codepen.io/jming422/pen/vOyrzQ) for your code, Ali, and added a function to handle the tooltip. You can check out the full code there, but here's what I added to your original code:

In the **HTML**, I wrapped your `seekslider` in a container and added a span for the tooltip like so:

```
<div id="seek-container">
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.1" /><span id="seek-tooltip"></span>
</div>
```

Then, with **CSS**, I:

- Ensured that the `seek-container` would remain inline like the slider ordinarily would.
- Set the `seek-tooltip` position to be absolute, or relative to the document (you'll see why in a bit), set it to be initially invisible, and gave it a nice shadow just for kicks.
- Made the `seek-tooltip` become visible with a white background when the `seek-container` is hovered over.

This was the code to do all that:

```
#seek-container {
    display: inline;
}

#seek-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}

#seek-container:hover #seek-tooltip {
    display: inline;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Finally, the good stuff: **JavaScript**. Now, despite the fact that you tagged this question jQuery, I noticed that your original code didn't include any, so I chose to follow your suit and not use jQuery in this answer. It's of course doable (likely a little easier), but I wanted this to flow as consistently as possible with what you already had.

Anyway, here's what I did:

- Added another variable to your list at the start: `tooltip`
- Stored the `seek-tooltip` element into that `tooltip` variable
- Added a `mousemove` event listener to your `seekslider` that called the function `sliderTooltip`
- Wrote the function `sliderTooltip`, which calculated the currently hovered time (thanks Jesse), set the contents of the tooltip to the time, set the tooltip's top position to that of the slider, and set the tooltip's left position to that of the mouse. This is why the tooltip's position is set to absolute: I'm using the `offsetTop` property of the slider to determine the necessary y-coordinate and the `pageX` property to grab the mouse's x-coordinate, both of which are relative to the document; making the tooltip positioned absolutely ensures that the tooltip and mouse are using the same coordinates.

Here's the code:

```
var tooltip; //This would be at the beginning with your other definitions

//--The stuff below would be inside your window.onload function--

//Populate your tooltip variable
tooltip = document.getElementById("seek-tooltip");
 //Bind the tooltip update function to the slider's mousemove event
seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", sliderTooltip, false);

//--Done with the stuff in your window.onload--

function sliderTooltip(e) { 
    //The parameter e is the mousemove event that was fired
    //First, calculate the current hovered time (thanks Jesse)
    var hoverTime = ((e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft) / e.target.clientWidth * parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute('max'))).toFixed(2);
    var hoverMins = Math.floor(hoverTime / 60);
    var hoverSecs = Math.floor(hoverTime - hoverMins * 60);

    //Now that we've got the time, simply populate the tooltip!
    tooltip.innerHTML = hoverMins + ":" + hoverSecs;
    //Set the "top" CSS to the top position of the slider
    tooltip.style.top = seekslider.offsetTop + "px";
    //Set the "left" CSS to our mouse position, plus 10 pixels
    //to offset it a bit to allow the user to click on the slider and not on the tooltip
    tooltip.style.left = (e.pageX + 10) + "px";
```

}
    }

If you're curious as to what the jQuery version would have looked like, it's close to exactly the same thing, save for the way the tooltip is selected and its event listener is added.

Comment: first, i have to say thank you so much for your work and i really appreciate it. secondly i have to say and im sorry but it shows the wrong time on the video. if you load your codepen : http://codepen.io/jming422/pen/vOyrzQ with this http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4 , you will see the time which this shows is wrong. also for some reason the tooltip doesnt popup in my code and i think its because of the z-index (i think)

Comment: You're welcome, it's been a fun learning experience, even for me :) Like Jesse said in his answer, the time is a best estimate, but it's pretty difficult to get the exact time. I'm not sure how to get the calculation to be more accurate, but toy around with the `hoverTime` calculation; see if you can improve it. As for the tooltip not displaying, that's because I forgot to set the `top` position, so it got pushed underneath the video! I've fixed it and updated my answer.

Comment: @jming First off, impressive dedication! I think the reason the time is a bit off is because I'm calculating the value of the slider itself, not the time. To get the time, you'll have to replace where I use the max attribute with the video duration: `((e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft) / e.target.clientWidth * vid.duration).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried **jming's answer** but to me, totally wrong value was being provided. After modifying like below, my problem was solved.

```
var hoverTime = (e.offsetX / e.target.clientWidth) * parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('max'),10);
```

This provides more accurate value of the time inside the slider.

Thanks to [jming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3869670/jming) for his awesome work.

Comment: I agree, had the same issue and this was my solution, so I voted for this answer.. however, the time is also affected by the size of the thumb for the slider. To get more accurate I had to do something like this:  `var hoverTime = ((e.offsetX - halfThumbWidth) / (e.target.clientWidth - thumbWidth)) * parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('max'),10);`

Comment: @FredArters you are closer, however if you are using react, e.offsetX is invalid and also I had to use ⅔ of my thumb width instead of half.

With a thumb width of 12px, here's how it worked out for me:
```const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
const maxRange = parseInt(input.getAttribute("max")!, 10);
const calculatedTime = ((e.nativeEvent.offsetX - 4) / (input.clientWidth - 12)) * maxRange```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i was working on this tooltip of current Time project and i got a script that i made myself that actually works just awesome it is the mixture of every code i have seen for this project

```js
 var video = $('video')[0];
 $('input').mousemove(function(e){
        var progress = $("input");
        var maxduration = video.duration;
        var position = e.pageX - progress.offset().left;
        var tooltip = $("span")[0];
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
        if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }
        var min = Math.floor((percentage / 100 * video.duration) / 60);
        var sec = Math.floor((percentage / 100 * video.duration) - min * 60); 
        if(min < 10){
            min = "0" + min;
        }
        if(sec < 10){
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        $("span").html(min + ":" + sec); 
  //You can use this code below to align your tooltip when you have completed styling it
  /*tooltip.style.top = -progress[0].offsetTop+(-10) + "px";
         console.log(progress.offset().top);
         tooltip.style.marginLeft = (e.pageX - 25) + "px";
  //Note: You may have to edit this code according to your styling
*/
});
//Just for testing
var timeDrag = false;
$('input').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timeDrag = true;
        video.pause();
        updatebar(e.pageX);
 });
   var updatebar = function(x) {
        var progress = $('input');

        //calculate drag position
        //and update video currenttime
        //as well as progress bar
        var maxduration = video.duration;
        var position = x - progress.offset().left;
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
        if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }
        video.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
    };
```

```css
input{
  width:400px; /*Just for demonstration that this code does not depend on width of the slider*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="https://givemesomething.000webhostapp.com/video.mp4" height="280" width="100%" controls></video> 
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
<span></span>
```

That's All it will work surely work thanks